# Continuity of a function - u(x,y) - Sequence is not converging by the function itself

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity

Let the real function of two real variables$$u(x,y) =   
\begin{cases}   
x,  & \quad \text{if } |y|>|x|  \\
 -x,  & \quad \text{if } otherwise
 \\    \end{cases} $$

Is there a sequence $\{(x_n,y_n)\}_{n \geq 0}$ which converge to $(0,0)$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} u(x_n,y_n) \not= u(0,0)$?

I tried to prove this by contrapositive of continuity, but I failed

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $|u(x,y) - u(0,0)| = |x|$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\{(x_n,y_n)\}$ converges to $(0,0)$, then in particular $\{x_n\}$ converges to $0$.  Thus for any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N$ such that $|x_n|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$.  But $|u(x,y)|=|x|$ for all $(x,y)$, so this means $|u(x_n,y_n)|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$.  Thus $\{u(x_n,y_n)\}$ converges to $0=u(0,0)$.